# How to delete all data from the package?

Tags: installation, package-management

Can you explain me how to delete all data from the specific program? I need to remove all user settings and data base of several packages. Specifically I wish delete all settings and media library from Rhythmbox and Clementine.

I tried to find their files in home folder, but cache of images is the only that I found there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following:

```
find . -type d -name rhythmbox

find . -type d -name clementine
```

That should find all folders named rhythmbox and clementine.

For example, the first one returns this

```
./.cache/rhythmbox
./.local/share/rhythmbox
```

...but I've no idea where Clementine's data is.

Comment: I just have to delete it, right?

Comment: it's strange… but `find . -type d -name clementine` shows nothing :)

Comment: `find . -type d  | grep clemen ` shows nothing too

Comment: How about `find .-type d -name *lemen*`? Theoretically, it could be storring settings anywhere.